# Statistical advantages of complex-valued random variables?

Tags: statistics, complex-numbers, random-variables

I am interested in random complex numbers and am trying to understand: why to use complex random variables in statistics?

Complex numbers can equally be viewed as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but with a defined multiplication (or $2\times 2$ matrices). This [thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66088/analysis-with-complex-data-anything-different) addresses how to *do* linear regression with complex data. There are also several discussions around the value of complex numbers in Quantum Mechanics, where you also encounter probabilistic behaviour.

I am aware complex-valued data arise in areas such as signal processing through complex numbers as a transform of real information. Alternatively, complex numbers can be constructed to represent a pair of real values and provide compact notation in other areas such as economics. Statistical operations are then run upon such data obeying the complex algebra. A common discussed benefit is compactness of notation, but do we also have calculation or computational benefits by taking advantage of $\mathbb{C}$ and its multiplication?

To ask another way, once you have complex-valued data, are there specific *statistical* (e.g. distribution, modelling, estimation) benefits by continuing to treat it in the complex field, rather than using real bivariate statistical methods?

(Note: This question was originally posted on [CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/513892/why-use-complex-valued-random-variables), however I am hoping to broaden the audience it reaches given that it originates as a consequence of other fields' use of complex numbers.)